# when i zoom imageview , and then click on image image goes off ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

note : this is how i have added this gesture to my imageview

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
    pinchGesture.delegate=self;
    [self.editPictureImageView  addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
```

note :  this is my method that handles pinch transformation
mcurrentscale  and mlastscale are of float type

```
-(void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender {

    mCurrentScale += [sender scale] - mLastScale;
    mLastScale = [sender scale];

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        mLastScale = 1.0;
    }

    if (mCurrentScale < 1)
    {
        mCurrentScale = 1.0;
    }

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform,    mCurrentScale, mCurrentScale);
    self.editPictureImageView.transform = newTransform;


}
```

plzz help

Comment: Not sure if this will do it, but you may want to reset your recognizer’s scale at the end of the method like this: `sender.scale = 0;`.

Comment: its not working zev .

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a more awkward way to do it.

I would re-think your approach like so:

Add the `UIImageView` to a `UIScrollView`. The frame of the imageView should be the bounds of the scrollView, by which I mean at it's default position it the imageView should sit in the scrollView just like it did whilst it was sitting in a normal view.

Set up the UIScrollView (IB or code):

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
//    example values
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.4f;
self.scrolLView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0f;
```

Adopt this method:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //  allow zooming of our image view
    return self.imageView;
}
```